# How can I change the created time of a file in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

I want have a resolution of milliseconds. Most command or tools that I found just allow me specified seconds, not  milliseconds. BTW, my files are on NTFS.

Comment: What do you want to set the time to? The current time or some other time in the past or future?

Comment: @DavidPostill Really not matter, cos what I want is set creation times to a set of files with a diff between them, in a precision of milliseconds. I mean, is the same if is in the past or in the future, what is important is the time difference between files.

Answer (score -1):

Using a piece of software it's easy. Maybe someone else can give you a Windows' command.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/filedatech.html

Some file systems allow ms resolution but, only ~10ms precision. So I guess most software doesn't want to deal with that.

And finally there's this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Are you sure that tool allow milliseconds precision? In the [UI screenshot](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/filedatech.gif) I saw just up to seconds precision.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not even sure NTFS file system resolution allows for this precision. It should, I'm not sure. But there's this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes [it does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx), that is why I'm  asking how set it.